# How can I send a message to every server my bot is in with python discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I'm trying to make my bot send a message in a channel in every server its in. I want to make an announcement saying something like "Thank you for inviting my bot to your server! We have now reached x amount of users!" Below is my code.

```py
import interactions
import os
import discord

import config
import settings
from settings import *
from utils import *

from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook
from discord.ext import commands
from config import *

bot = interactions.Client(token=BOT_TOKEN)
webhook = DiscordWebhook(url=WEBHOOK_URL, rate_limit_retry=True, content="Online..")
response = webhook.execute()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    config.ABSOLUTE_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    config.COOKIE_PATH = config.ABSOLUTE_PATH + config.COOKIE_PATH

    if config.BOT_TOKEN == "":
        print("Error: No bot token!")
        exit


async def register(guild):

    guild_to_settings[guild] = Settings(guild)

    sett = guild_to_settings[guild]

    try:
        await guild.me.edit(nick=sett.get('default_nickname'))
    except:
        pass

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(STARTUP_MESSAGE)

    for guild in bot.guilds:
        await register(guild)
        print("Active in {}".format(guild.name))
    
    print(config.STARTUP_COMPLETE_MESSAGE)
    
@bot.command(
    name="message",
    description="This description isn't seen in UI (yet?)",
    options=[
        interactions.Option(
            name="global_message",
            description="A descriptive description",
            type=interactions.OptionType.SUB_COMMAND,
            options=[
                interactions.Option(
                    name="text",
                    description="A descriptive description",
                    type=interactions.OptionType.STRING,
                    required=True,
                ),
            ],
        ),
        interactions.Option(
            name="local_message",
            description="A descriptive description",
            type=interactions.OptionType.SUB_COMMAND,
            options=[
                interactions.Option(
                    name="text",
                    description="A descriptive description",
                    type=interactions.OptionType.STRING,
                    required=True,
                ),
            ],
        ),
    ],
)
async def cmd(ctx: interactions.CommandContext, sub_command: str, message: str = "", text: int = None):
    if sub_command == "global_message":
        channel = bot.get_channel(1062062016602308620)
        await channel.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} said: {text}")

    elif sub_command == "local_message":
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} said: {message}")
        
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.defer()
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for text_channel in guild.text_channels:
            try:
                await text_channel.send("Thank you for inviting my bot to your server! We have now reached x amount of users!")
                break
            except: pass
    await ctx.followup.send("Sent")

bot.start(BOT_TOKEN)
```

I'm using the libraries interactions, os, discord-webhook and discord.

Hope you guys can help me!
let me know if I can describe it better :D

So far I can see the command /ping but the command will load for a few seconds and then fail to load.

Comment: This is incredibly spammy & will make a lot of people instantly kick your bot from their server (_especially_ if you send it in _every channel_ as well - as if once per server wasn't bad enough). Consider if you really want to add this. Also, the `interactions` library is unnecessary, interaction-related things are already built-in to `discord.py`.

Answer (score 0):

You already got the guilds that your bot is in using [`discord.Client.guilds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guilds#discord.Client.guilds) (bot.guilds), after that you can get guild text channels using [`discord.Guild.text_channels`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guilds#discord.Guild.text_channels), you can loop through all the channels with a try-except statemtent so you can pass raises like ([`discord.Forbidden`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guilds#discord.Forbidden)) that you get if you don't have the proper permissions to send the message, if there's not errors you can then break the loop using the `break` statement otherwise if will keep sending the message to all guild channels.

Here is a simple code if you want to use:

```
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for text_channel in guild.text_channels:
            try:
                await text_channel.send("Thank you for inviting my bot to your server! We have now reached x amount of users!")
                break
            except: pass
```

For interactions you can use this code:

```
@bot.slash_command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.defer()
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for text_channel in guild.text_channels:
            try:
                await text_channel.send("Thank you for inviting my bot to your server! We have now reached x amount of users!")
                break
            except: pass
    await ctx.followup.send("Sent")
```

Comment: When I do that my message in my discord server says "sending..." then a few seconds after I get a "The application didn't respond.." I also get this error message: TypeError: ping() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: The `ctx` argument is missing in the function parameters

Comment: Yes, I forgot to put the ctx parameter, sorry.

Comment: Also about the "The application didn't respond..", you get this when your interaction takes too long to send a response or didn't have a response! In that case you have to defer it using [https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=defer#discord.InteractionResponse.defer](`discord.InteractionResponse.defer`) (`ctx.defer()`) before the guild for-loop and give it a response for e.g: `ctx.send("Sent!")` after the guild for-loop.

Comment: Where do I put the ctx parameter? Also, I can't seem to get the defer to work either. 

Comment: About the ctx parameter I've already edited my source code! I also added an interaction code! that you can use or see how it works.

Comment: Thank you! but now I get this error message: AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'slash_command'. Did you mean: 'message_command'?

Comment: Can I see your source code! I mean the part of the interaction!

Comment: yes! i will edit my original post and put it in.

Comment: Just change `@bot.slash_command()` by `@bot.command()` and the parameters you want to use same as the message command above! I just noticed it's a webhook :)

Comment: I get this error message: TypeError: Client.start() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given which is my line 100: bot.start(BOT_TOKEN). The command ping doesnt show up.

Comment: my end goal with my bot is I want people to make a #global-chat inside their server. This is where people can talk across servers by using the /globalchat command in my bot. So i want it to only be able to talk inside a specific set channel. if you have ever played clash of clans they had a global chat where you could talk to people across guilds. i want my bot to do that but in discord in one channel.

Comment: Global chat was a feature in Clash of Clans that allowed players to interact on a global level and find an appropriate clan and friends.

Comment: can u reedit the source code! with the new one?

Comment: I reedited it now. :D

Comment: Well your problem is that you are using token in bot.start() it doesnt require token you already used it in insteraction.Client(token=...). Also I suggest you use discordpy for interactions... because the interaction library you use in bot.guild it returns the guild name not the Object! that means you cant guild text_channels....! my code will be helpful if u use discord.py instead of interactions library.